# Using Beautiful Soup to scrape a popup that has a URL (and else error)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project for science that scrapes skyward.smsd.org it opens in a pop up but at the top of the page it has a URL when I go to it not in the popup it says your session has expired and there is no way around this I can find. I am also having an invalid syntax error with else: msg if anyone can help me find a solution to these issues

```
while True:

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    from time import sleep
    url = "https://skyward.smsd.org/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsEAplus/sfcalendar002.w"

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
from requests.packages.urllib3 import add_stderr_logger

add_stderr_logger()
s = requests.Session()

s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'

login = {login: 3078774, password: (MY PASSWORD)}
login_response = s.post(url, data=login)
for r in login_response.history:
    if r.status_code == 401:  # 401 means authentication failed
        sys.exit(1)  # abort

pdf_response = s.get(pdf_url)  # Your cookies and headers are automatically included

if str(soup).find("skyward") == -1:
    continue

time.sleep(60)



else:
     msg = 'Subject: This is the script talking, check Skyward'

#Possibilty to make this tell you exactly what is changed
#A text feature that goes out daily for missing assignments
fromaddr = '3078774@smsd.org'

toaddrs  = ['3078774@smsd.org']



print('From: ' + fromaddr)
print('To: ' + str(toaddrs))
print('Message: ' + msg)

break
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. I'm not sure how much is in your actual code and how much due to incorrectly copy/pasting it here, but what is here has multiple indentation issues. Including just before the `else` which is raising the error. (I would assume the `time.sleep(60)` is supposed to be indented, which would fix that error - but then that line of code would never be reached. Not sure what your intention is.)

Comment: Thank you I fixed the error but the pop up is still an issue